# Injecting properties into log4net's LoggingEvent

Tags: logging, log4net

I'm trying to figure out a way to inject properties into log4net's LoggingEvent.  Each time an event is created via a logging method, eg:

```
log.Warn(...);
log.Info(...);
log.Error(...);
```

etc.

I would like to be able to add properties to the LoggingEvent that's created, Properties property.

Using reflector I can see that when a logging method is called it eventually instantiates a LoggingEvent instance, if the level for the event is equal to or more critical than the threshold set on the logger.  This LoggingEvent has a Properties property of type PropertiesDictionary, basically a map of name/value pairs.  I would like to be able to add properties to that dictionary without the user having to make any additional calls.

The only way I can think of doing this is if somehow I can wrap the logger returned from LogManager.GetLogger().  And I don't mind doing that, but it can't be via code, I would need to make this happen via log4net configuration.  I've been searching around and can't see any way to wrap things via configuration.

I think it would also work to add properties to the thread context objects, but again this has to happen automatically without the user doing it via code.  Is there any way for me to hook into the thread context objects via configuration so that some code of mine would get called each time a context is being created for a log statement?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the stacks feature in log4net: [stacks log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html)

Stacks enable you to add information in a context and log it with your messages:

```
using(log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push("context"))
{
    log.Info("Message");
}
```

This will add 'context' into your log output, you have to add it in your log line formatter.

Comment: No, that won't work as the user has to code that.  I'm looking for a way for me to inject my own code so that each time a LoggingEvent is created I can add properties to it.